# Java source code parser in Ruby

Tags: java, ruby, parsing, code-generation

Working on a code generation tool to help creating boiler code for our project.

The generator is written in ruby with erb templates, the project itself is in Java.

Now I am looking for a **ruby gem/library for parsing java source files**, given a string from a .java files, get the imports, methods, fields, class name etc etc, that would enable me to navigate to a certain method and appending code to it etc (kinda like jQuery selector).

I am wondering if there are already solutions that I can use, kinda like the `javaclass-rb` library, but that is for parsing bytecodes from .class files.

I know I could use ANTLR and a ruby adapter, but I hope there are existing solutions.

Thanks!

Comment: Is JRuby okay? Then you could use any Java library, like [javaparser](http://code.google.com/p/javaparser/). I don't know of any pure-Ruby libraries to do this.

Comment: Thanks @Niklas, that's a great idea that opens up so many possibilities, I am using ruby mostly for the nice concise language and erb, so switching to JRuby should be fine. Still hope there is a pure ruby library for it but this should do just fine for now.

Comment: In that case, I'll post the suggestion as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[JRuby](http://jruby.org/) is a Ruby implementation on top of the JVM that make interaction between Ruby and Java objects trivial. If you decide to use this, you can use any Java library to solve the task, like [javaparser](http://code.google.com/p/javaparser/).

Comment: Seems the logical choice for a Java-focused project.